# Three.js - How to move a Ball from left to right repeatedly

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, rendering

I want to move a Ball in Three.js to right and then it shall move to the start position and then back to the right repeatedly.

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {specular: "#fdfb57", 
color: "#d8d613", emissive: "#6b6a0d", side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var ball = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// What programming code I have to put on here? 
};

render();
```

But how should I implement the Moving of the ball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either by changing `ball.position` on every frame or by using a library like [Tween.js](http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs) to get the motion path between the two points you want to move between.

For a simple left-to-right-reverse-repeat animation, you're well off with simply adjusting the position.

Try pasting this into [avgp.github.io/h2g2three](http://avgp.github.io/h2g2three):

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {specular: "#fdfb57", color: "#d8d613", emissive: "#6b6a0d", side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var ball = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var dxPerFrame = 1; // how to move in a single frame

scene.add(ball);

onRender = function() {
  ball.position.x += dxPerFrame; // move ball
  if(ball.position.x >  100) dxPerFrame = -1; // if we're too far right, move towards the left
  if(ball.position.x < -100) dxPerFrame =  1; // if we're too far left, move towards the right again
};

// Alt+Return run the code
```